# Reflexive modules and the canonical map $M\to \operatorname{Hom}_R(\operatorname{Hom}_R(M,N),N)$

Tags: commutative-algebra, modules, homological-algebra, noetherian

Let $R$ be a commutative Noetherian ring. For any $R$-module $M,N$, there exists a canonical map $d_{M,N}: M \to \operatorname{Hom}_R(\operatorname{Hom}_R(M,N),N)$ sending an element $m \in M$ to the map $\operatorname{Hom}_R(M,N) \to N$ $(f \mapsto f(m))$. Now let $M$ be a finitely generated reflexive $R$-module. If $N \cong R$ , then $M\cong \operatorname{Hom}_R(\operatorname{Hom}_R(M,N),N)$.

My question is: If $M$ is a finitely generated reflexive $R$-module and $N\cong R$, then is the map $d_{M,N}$ an isomorphism?

Comment: What are your thoughts on this problem and why do you think it is non-trivial?

Comment: An $R$-module is reflexive by definition if $d_{M,R}$ is an isomorphism.

Comment: @Claudius: I think I have explained my motivations for the problem clearly. The non-triviality of the problem is finding a connection between $d_{M,N}$ and $d_{M,R}$ ...

Comment: @Berci: yes but it is not clear what the connection between $d_{M,N}$ and $d_{M,R}$ is ...

Comment: If $N\cong R$, then clearly $\hom(M,N)\cong\hom(M,R)$ and $\hom(\hom(M,N),N)\cong \hom(\hom(M,R),R)$. Your question then reduces to why $d_{M,N}$ corresponds to exactly $d_{M,R}$ using the above isomorphism. But you can keep track of it fixing the element $e$ of $N$ which corresponds to  $1\in R$..

Answer (score 1):

Let $\varphi:R\to N$ be an isomorphism, then it induces an isomorphism
$$\tilde\varphi:\hom_R(\hom_R(M,N),\,N)\to\hom_R(\hom_R(M,R),\,R)\\
\tilde\varphi(F)=\underset{M\to R}f\mapsto \varphi^{-1}\left( F(\varphi\circ f)\right)\,$$
and for the evaluation map $d_{M,N}$, i.e. setting $F=d_{M,N}(m)$ in the above, we get
$$\tilde\varphi\circ d_{M,N}(m)=\underset{M\to R}f \mapsto\varphi^{-1}(\varphi\circ f(m))=f\mapsto f(m)=d_{M,R}(m)\,.$$
So, $d_{M,N}$ is an isomorphism if and only if $d_{M,R}$ is.